# Maven Surefire doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Good morning,

I've got a test working great in eclipe. I'm trying to use Maven to do a mvn test via the command line and for some reason it keeps blanking out and doing nothing on the surefire line.

```
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ esign ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Rest API Projects\Maven\Docusign\esign\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ esign ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ esign ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Rest API Projects\Maven\Docusign\esign\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ esign ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Rest API Projects\Maven\Docusign\esign\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ esign ---
```

I can't figure out why it isn't actually running the java like it's supposed to. Heres a look at config in my pom.xml as well.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DocusignRun</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surfire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                            <include>WorkingDemo.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I'm new to java (just learned it a few weeks ago) so any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you want me to provide anything else to determine whats going on here.

Thanks!

Comment: First locate the unit test in `src/test/java` and name it accordingly which means `*Test.java` and remove the profile you have defined ....

Comment: I CANT BELIEVE ALL I NEEDED TO DO WAS NAME IT TEST! Holy moley lmao. Thank you so much